# using static boolean method

Tags: java, methods, static, boolean

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonthMapper{
    static String month;
    static int month_num;

    public static boolean isMonthNumber (String str) { 
        month = str;
        month_num = Integer.parseInt(month);
        return (month_num >= 0 && month_num < 12); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Month: ");
        month = sc.next();
        System.out.println (isMonthNumber (Integer.toString(month_num)));
    }
}
```

I have to write a static class method `boolean isMonthNumber(String str)` that takes a String as an input and returns boolean value. The method returns `True` if the input string represents an integer value between 1 and 12, otherwise the method returns should return `False`.

Currently for some reason my program always returns true even when i enter a value greater than 12.

Comment: No. It returns true if I enter `1`

Comment: What is the value of `month_num` when you invoke `Integer.toString(month_num)`? How do you figure?

Comment: you're right it does, but when i enter a number larger than 12, it also returns true

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis It's supposed to convert the integer from user input back into a string so it can be printed, so it can be any integer that the user has inputted

Comment: What is the current specific value of `month_num` when you invoke `Integer.toString(month_num)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `mounth_num` variable to a method, but the `month` variable has the read value.

Replace with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter Month: ");
  System.out.println(isMonthNumber (sc.next()));
}
```

Comment: I see, but now I have to enter the input twice for the program to work, how can i make it so i only have to input once?
Edit: nevermind I realized how silly a question this was.

Thank you very much for your swift answer! :-)